# What htaccess rule would you use to redirect users already using the secure version of your site to purely secure links without affecting HTTP access?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

Basically if somebody is already on an HTTPS page, I don't want them to be capable of being redirected to/accidentally clicking an HTTP one (on the same site at least). It seems to me like you would use the referer as a RewriteCond to accomplish this, except for the fact that it is apparently browser policy not to send referers when going from HTTPS pages to HTTP ones. So if a user loads an HTTP page, how can I detect if they came from an HTTPS one and make sure they are redirected to the secure version of the page they are trying to access?

Unfortunately the software we are using has many hardcoded HTTP links so it is necessary to use some sort of redirection.

Comment: This is nothing that should be taken care of by means of a rewrite rule. You have to make sure _all_ links you hand out will lead to https requests. Easiest is to use relative links for that. And apart from that: is there a single reason why you would want to still support http access if you have a valid and working https service?

Comment: Like I said, that is not possible for the moment with the software we're using. It will be done, but we need a solution for now. Meanwhile we wish to support http because it's faster and some users don't care about security.

Comment: This sounds like you want to advertise a mail service that accepts the privacy request of customers and promises _never_ to have unauthorized people see what messages are transported and then putting all envelopes on public display on a regular schedule...

Comment: I'm sorry but it was my understanding that this site was not for the exchange of subjective opinions. We will have to debate the relative merits of universal encryption somewhere else. Do you have a solution to my problem or not?

Comment: The solution obviously is to use a RewriteCondition that tests if https is actually used and rewrite if not: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on`.

Comment: However this is _not_ a thing of personal or subjective opinions. It is simply a question of offering a serious service. Offering https on the paper and then secretly exposing your users data to be readable by everyone on the internet is simply fraud. It is highly unprofessional too. Especially if you know you do that.

Comment: Oh, and... your redirection approach can only work for GET requests, it will _not_ work for POST requests which makes the data exposure even more serious.

Comment: Won't that rewrite condition return false if the user is loading an http page, that is, if they clicked an http link?

Comment: No, why? That is what you asked for if I am not totally mistaken. If that condition is fulfilled, so if https is _not_ used, then you want to rewrite from http to https.

Comment: I only want them to be redirected to https if they came from an https page already. I want the http version of the site to be fully usable otherwise.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad, forgot that condition during the discussion. Sorry.

Comment: Actually I don't see any means to detect that. At least nothing reliable.

Comment: I don't really understand _why_ your solution cannot be modified such that it is using relative links which would solve your issue. In the end that would be a global search and replace... But at least that solution should be able to work on different hostnames, since otherwise it would be impossible to port it? If so then you could use two separate hostnames, say `http ://www.example.org` and `https ://secure.example.org`. That would allow separate and non-mixed operation and prevent that mile wide security gap.

Comment: We don't want to deviate from upstream. We're waiting on them.

Comment: How can that be? You say you have hard coded links including the protocol scheme _and_ the hostname _from an upstream project_ ? Sorry, but that makes no sense. don't get me wrong, I am not trying to be an asshole :-) I am trying to find some solution that makes sense. But an _upstream_ solution, so a solution for several installations with a hard coded hostname? No way.

Comment: The hostname part is dynamically configured, but the links it generates just happen to be hardcoded to http. Don't ask me why.

Comment: OK, then it can't be done. Your only option is to switch to https completely then. Or do _you_ see any other alternative?

Comment: Carefully chosing which links to click

Comment: OK, lol, sounds like a great user experience. Good luck!